# how to create hdf5 dataset with early allocate and no fill using h5py

Tags: file-io, io, hdf5, hpc, h5py

I am trying to create a 78TB HDF5 dataset by filling it in a 2d block-partition manner. This is very slow when the block I'm writing spans rows that haven't ever been written to, because HDF5 is going in and allocating the diskspace and filling in the missing entries with zero.

Instead, I would like h5py to allocate the disk space for my dataset as soon as its created, and never fill it. This is possible with the C api according to Table 16 in [the HDF5 Dataset documentation](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc1.6/UG/10_Datasets.html), but how can I do this with h5py, preferably with the high level interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Quincey suggested. You can use the low-level H5py API to create the dataset with the FILL_TIME_NEVER property then convert it back to a high-level Dataset object:

```py
# create the rows dataset using the low-level api so I can force it to not do zero-filling, then convert to a high level object
spaceid = h5py.h5s.create_simple((numRows, numCols))
plist = h5py.h5p.create(h5py.h5p.DATASET_CREATE)
plist.set_fill_time(h5py.h5d.FILL_TIME_NEVER)
plist.set_chunk((rowchunk, colchunk))
datasetid = h5py.h5d.create(fout.id, "rows", h5py.h5t.NATIVE_DOUBLE, spaceid, plist)
rows = h5py.Dataset(datasetid)
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you want to set the fill time to "never", with the H5Pset_fill_time() routine, but I don't know the h5py way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying a chunk shape that matches your write pattern.  For example if you are writing in blocks of 1024x1024, it would look like this:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
f = h5py.File('mybigdset.h5', 'w')
dset = f.create_dataset('dset', (78*1024*1024, 1024*1024), dtype='f4', chunks=(1024,1024))
arr = np.random.rand(1024,1024)
dset[0:1024, 0:1024] = arr
f.close()
```

Thankfully, this didn't use 78TB of disk, the file size was just 4MB.

Comment: I forgot the line where the file was created, this would be just before the create_dataset call: f = h5py.File('mybigdset.h5', 'w')

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I'm producing this file for use in an application where the access is going to be in blocks of rows, so I don't want to use chunking.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... what's the downside of using chunking?

Comment: The blocks I'm able to write at a time are tall and skinny, so using those as chunks would be inefficient for reading in terms of rows. But I think if I set the chunk size reasonably, I will be able to read rows at a reasonable granularity. E.g. my output matrix is 132,710,400 by 81,600, and each process can write a chunk of 26,542,080 by 8 at a time, so if I do collective writing into blocks of size 1024 by 480 (3.75MB), I will have 129,600-by-170 blocks when I'm reading in, so have a high level of granularity over the row reading. I will update you when I see how this works :)